# How to Define the Monodromy Action on the Universal Cover

Tags: manifolds, group-actions, covering-spaces, monodromy

Let $M$ be a connected manifold, and let $\rho : \tilde{M} \to M$ be its universal covering. Fix $x_0 \in M$. I know how to define the $\pi_1(M,x_0)$-action on the fiber $\pi^{-1}[\{x_0\}] \subseteq \tilde{M}$, and this is called the *monodromy action*. I want to know whether $\pi_1(M,x_0)$ acts on the whole $\tilde{M}$. That is, is there a natural way to define $\tilde{x} \cdot [\gamma]$ for $\tilde{x} \in \tilde{M}$ and $[\gamma] \in \pi_1(M,x_0)$ even if $\rho(\tilde{x}) \ne x_0$?

I guess one way to define this is the following. Let $\tilde{x} \in \tilde{M}$ and $[\gamma] \in \pi_1(M,x_0)$ be given. Let $x = \rho(\tilde{x})$. Pick any curve $\delta$ in $M$ from $x_0$ to $x$. Then $\delta^{-1} \gamma \delta$ is a loop at $x$ in $M$. Define $\tilde{x} \cdot [\gamma] = \tilde{x} \cdot [\delta^{-1} \gamma \delta]$.

For this, I have to show that this does not depend on the choice of $\delta$ (and $\gamma$).

In short, I do not know

1. whether there is a way to define the action,
2. even if 1 is true, whether the above way is the correct way, and
3. even if 2 is true, how to prove the well-definedness.

I have Lee's *Introduction to Topological/Smooth/Riemannian Manifolds*, Bredon's *Topology and Geometry*. So I can freely use theorems in them. Thank you.

Comment: My first guess would be that this is well defined if and only if $\pi_1(M)$ is abelian. Otherwise I suspect that you run into the same problem as we do when comparing $\pi_1(M,x_0)$ to $\pi_1(M,x)$. The groups are isomorphic, by "conjugating with $\delta$", but the resulting isomorphism depends on the choice of $\delta$. In other words, if $\delta'$ is another connecting path, then the two resulting "actions" differ from each other if conjugation by $\delta\delta'$ is not the identity in $\pi_1(M,x_0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bar{M}$ is the set of curves $\alpha:[0,1]\to M, \alpha(0)=x_0$ quotiented by $\alpha\sim \alpha_2$ if $\alpha(1)=\alpha_2(1)$ and $\alpha\cup \alpha_2^-$ is equal in $\pi_1(M,x_0)$ to the trivial curve $Tr(t)=x_0$.

The action of $\pi_1(M,x_0)$ on $\bar{M}$ is $\gamma\cdot\alpha  = \gamma\cup \alpha$.

As $M$ is a connected manifold then $\bar{M}$ is a covering space. $\bar{M}$ is simply connected because
a closed-loop $f:Tr\to Tr$ in $\bar{M}$ is represented by a continuous function $f:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to M$ such that $f(t,0)=f(0,t)=f(1,t)=x_0$, each $f(t,.)$ is an element of $\bar{M}$, and the continuous function $g:[0,1]\times [0,1]\times [0,1]\to M$, $g(r,t,s)=f((1-r)t,s)$ represents an homotopy from $f$ to the trivial loop at $Tr$.